# Not able to get correct value of range slider in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to store the value of a range slider in local storage.

.html

```
<div class="seekbar_div">
                    <input class="seekbar" id="#light_seek" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" onchange="rangevalue.value=value">
            </div>
```

.js

```
var sliderVal = document.getElementById("#light_seek").value;
    alert(sliderVal);
               localStorage.setItem("light_seek", sliderVal);
```

Here even if i change the slider to some other position than 0 still the alert is showing zero

Comment: `onchange="rangevalue.value=value"` not sure what you're after with this piece, but if you open console you'll see some error: `rangevalue is not defined`

Answer (score 3):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/loheqo/5/edit?html,js,console,output)***

`id="#light_seek"` you have an extra `#` here.

HTML:

```
<div class="seekbar_div">
  <input class="seekbar" id="light_seek" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var lightSeek = document.getElementById("light_seek");
var sliderVal = lightSeek.value;

console.log(sliderVal);

lightSeek.addEventListener("change", function(){  // event listener
   sliderVal = this.value;                        // modify var
   localStorage.setItem("light_seek", sliderVal); // Store to LS
   console.log( sliderVal );                      // test
}, false); 

// whenever you want to grab your value back from LS do:
// sliderVal = localStorage.getItem("light_seek");
```

Also, as you can see I've removed any HTML-inline JS cause it's bad practice for it's hardly maintainable. Try always to keep your HTML markup JS-free.

Comment: But she gets the element with "#light_seek"

Comment: Does using "#light_seek" affect the alerting 0 as the sliderVal? could you explain more?

Comment: @plbsam please in CSS, make the text red: http://jsbin.com/jewasa/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: got it. Thanks..  The problem is with CSS. not with js right?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i can see nothing in the console.Sir,actually i want this to be done on the click of a button